# CentOS connected to Internet but not updates

Tags: ubuntu, networking, yum

I have installed CentOS 6.3, OpenSUSE 12.1 and Ubuntu 12.04 on VMware Workstation 9. On any of these when I use `ping` to check network connectivity, I receive a proper answer, but when try to update them using `yum`, `yast` and `apt-get`, they all return error message like "can't reach repository".

I changed network setting in OSs and also in VMware over and over, but nothing happened.

Also from CentOS (and probably other OSs) I cannot use firefox to access internet also cannot use wget to fetch a page such as yahoo.com, it says: "Connecting to yahoo.com (yahoo.com)|98.138.253.109|:80... failed: Connection refused.
"

on Ubuntu I do/see this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get update
Err http://packages.mate-desktop.org precise InRelease
Err http://packages.mate-desktop.org precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to packages.mate-desktop.org:http:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease      
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease    
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease    
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to packages.mate-desktop.org:http:    
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:    
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http:    
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you pinging my IP or name? Is your DNS properly configured?

Comment: I do `ping yahoo.com`.

Comment: Update the question with _exact_ errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that you have some proxy/network policy in the way.

For Ubuntu/Debian you could try [this set of instructions on using an http proxy with apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy) if you know you have an http proxy.

For Fedora/CentOS [this set of instructions for proxy with yum](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/YumAndRPM#head-ea1fc5d78f578114f4843e57627ebae9cc4fcb5a).

Or [this for yast](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3662280).

If, in fact, it is a proxy issue.

Comment: I do not set any proxy server, I just installed these OSs. I run vmware on Windows 7, that has nothing special.

Comment: Windows has the ability to "discover" some types of proxies.  If all three are failing, it's probably network policy or proxies.  Network policy you have to set update tools to operate over port 80 to get around it.

Comment: I changed proxy settings int windows 7 but nothing happened, it seems this the problem has a different reason.